# How to print out function on a txt file

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

```
int main() {

    cout << "DECIMAL            BINARY      HEXDECIMAL              BCD" << endl;

    for (int num = 0; num <= 255; num++) {


    cout << decimalNum << "         ";
    DecitoBin(decimalNum);
    cout << "   ";
    DecitoHexi(decimalNum);
    cout << "               ";
    cout << DecitoBCD(decimalNum);
    cout << endl;




    }

    return 0;
}
```

So i did my program and i have to write all those statements to a txt file.

im not sure if this is correct, but i think this is how im supposed to start it off

```
ofstream outputFile("program0.txt");
//... An example of how to write to a txt file
outputFile << "writing to file";
```

but im not sure how it works when i have to write to a file using the different functions.

Comment: You can just replace ``cout`` with ``outputFile``

Comment: does it have to be within the loop? or outside of the loop? Im guessing inside the loop makes more sense now that i think about it.

Comment: First initialize your file stream before the loop  and then ``outputFile<< num <<..`` in that ``for`` loop

Comment: thanks, i remodified my code and im having an issue where its not priniting everything. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cout` is tied with file pointer `stdout`, which is C's standard output file pointer. So you can call `freopen` to redirect it to a file.

You can just write like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    //      filename     mode   file pointer

    cout << "DECIMAL            BINARY      HEXDECIMAL              BCD" << endl;

    for (int num = 0; num <= 255; num++) {
        cout << num << "            ";
        cout << binary(num) << "    ";
        cout << hex(num) << "               ";
        cout << bcd(num);
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And to reset the file pointer, you can call `freopen("CON", "w", stdout)` on windows, or `freopen("/dev/console", "w", stdout)` on linux.